# How to monitor apache/mysql webserver

Tags: mysql, apache, drupal, amazon-ec2, monitoring

I'm running a Drupal 7 site on Amazon EC2
Since this is a micro instance, once in a while the site crash
usually it is mysql but sometimes apache

I could write a php script connecting to database, return some OK/NOTOK code 
and then monitor that script using cron and restart mysql or apache service
however this looks very basic and while I couldn't find anything ready 
I don't want to invent the wheel..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't amazon offer anything like that out of the box?

Comment: Never mind my earlier comment, it was wrong but anywys, it could be easier to write a shell script for that instead of a php script.

Comment: Not as far as I know. They offer instance monitoring, CPU and bandwidth alets. I couldn't find apache or mysql monitoring.

Comment: Pingdom.com. You'd still want a script that connects to the database so it can report success/failure via its HTTP checks, but no reason to cron.

Comment: Besides Pingdom, you might also try Nagios. You can have a new micro instance with it installed, or even install it in the same micro node.

Comment: You can refer Manage Engine application manager to monitor any webserver http://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/webservice-monitoring.html

Answer (score 1):

You may use Monit to monitor the mySQL and other relevant processes in your server. It can also monitor network connections including http which you may use to monitor for your website.

http://mmonit.com/monit/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free monitoring service such as [GotSiteMonitor.com](http://www.gotsitemonitor.com) to monitor your site and check for OK/NOTOK strings in your page.